# symbols and reflection in Dart

Tags: dart

what is the usage and benefit of the term of reflection and Symbol dataType,

why can it really make my application difference?

**i need an illustration of this term.**

**this is an example:**

```
for (Symbol memberName in cm.staticMembers.keys) {

    print('$memberName');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Symbol` class in Dart represents *source names* at runtime.

When Dart reflection refers to the name of something, be it a library, class, type, instance method, or anything else with a name that can be reflected, that name is represented as a `Symbol` instead of a `String.

Examples include all names exposed by `dart:mirror`, but also non-`dart:mirror` reflection functionality like:

- The named argument names passed to [`Function.apply`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Function/apply.html)
- The named argument names received by `noSuchMethod` [`Invocation`s](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Invocation-class.html).

So, if you want to have `noSuchMethod` intercept the `foo` method, you can do:

```dart
noSuchMethod(invocation) {
  if (invocation.isMethod && invocation.memberName == #foo) {
    // do something
  } else { 
    return super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
  }
}
```

When writing symbol names, always use symbol literals (`#foo`) or constant `Symbol`  invocations (`const Symbol("foo")`). Never use `new Symbol(...)`.

You shouldn't need to use symbols outside of those cases:

- Comparing to a symbol provided by `Invocation`: `invocation.memberName == #foo`
- Passing a name to `Function.apply`: `Function.apply(f, [], {#name: 42})`
- Interacting with the `dart:mirrors` reflection system where it requires or provides a `Symbol`: `libraryMirror.declarations[#foo]`

It's sometimes convenient to use a private symbol like `#_foo` as a unique marker or sentinel value that code outside the library cannot create. It's really just a library-specific value then, and is not used as a symbol.

The original reason for having `Symbol` instead of just using strings was that JavaScript compilation would be able to rename variables without breaking `dart:mirrors` functionality, and it would be better able to tree-shake unused symbols to make the compiled program smaller. Now that compiling to the web no longer supports `dart:mirrors`, the advantage is reduced to the symbols used by `Function.apply` and `Invocation`.

Comment: Updated with examples.